# How to create a digital fingerprint for different observations?

Tags: variables, design-patterns, statistics, similarity

I know the title is a bit vage, but I couldn't think of a better one. Please let me explain the situation first:

normally when you got a real world observation you transcode them into variables. Like variable = sex, male == 0, female == 1 etc. So you only need to think about the type of scale you can use (ordinal, metric, etc.)

In my "special" case, I deal with sth. similar to cocktails (to make it more fun to talk about :-) )
Every cocktail (= observation) does have different ingredients, like gin, orange juice etc. and you have different types of ingredients as well, like juices and liquors.

Now I want do computations regarding the similarity between different cocktails, so I created a variable for each ingredient and sorted them by type, so variables 1-20 are liquors and 21-30 are juices. Each variable is binary coded (1/0). So when I look a the result I do get a kind of "digital fingerprint" of each cocktail.

example:

> cocktail A = 1 0 0 1 1 0 cocktail B = 0 0 0 1 0 0

Now I can use different techniques like SVM etc. to analyze similarities and differences.

Problem:

The variables correspond to different groups (liquors,etc.) so although two cocktails differ with respect to the kind of liquor they consist of, they may have in common that they use the same kind of liquor and/or same amount of liquors. How can I implement this information into the given structure and how can I weight that?
The second problem is about the borders of the groups:

example:

> 1. variable = orange juice
> 2. variable = apple juice
> 3. variable = whiskey
> 4. variable = gin

now I want to achieve that variations within the same group are not that bad as variations between the groups, so when you plot this as stem plot you notice that deviations from var2 to the left is a within move and to right would leave the group. So an overlay of two cocktails should resemble that huge difference.

example:

> cocktail A = 0 1 0 1
>
> cocktail B = 1 0 0 1
>
> cocktail C = 0 0 1 1

So I want to make sure that my system recognizes cocktail A + B to be more similar than A + C

Do have any suggestions for me? Thank you very much!